# Run VLC with oldrc at startup on raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc-media-player, raspbian, autostart

The problem I'm facing is the following: we have a raspberry PI zero that we want to use as a media player with custom hardware buttons as controls for playback. For we need to lunch an instance of VLC with when the PI boots with the follwing command:

```
vlc -I oldrc --rc-unix=/path/to/socket.sock /path/to/media/file
```

It all works when I do it manually on the terminal, but I wont wotk when I program i to do it at boot. I tried .desktop autostart and local.rc without success. I also changed the permissions of the .sock to anyone just to be safe (and because one cannot run vlc as root)

Any suggestion is very much welcome